# variable string in child variable of object is ignored

Tags: php, oop, class

I'm trying to load libraries dynamically with a loop then add them to `$this` and I'm trying to use instanceof to see if it's already been initiated before trying to initiate it again:

```
    $libraries = array('strings');
    foreach ($libraries as $lib) {
        require_once('lib/'.$lib.'.lib.php');
        if(!($this->lib_{$lib} instanceof $lib)){
            $this->lib_{$lib} = new $lib();
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
```

But when I try this I just get an 500 internal server error from apache.

The error I get is:

```
[15-Feb-2012 10:31:21] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: load::$lib_ in /home/wwwsrv/public_html/system/core.lib.php on line 57
```

(line 57 refers to the line with the `if` statement)

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the error message from the log?

Comment: check your error log. every error 500 logs should be written on that file *on normal installation*

Comment: Updated question with the error I'm getting

Comment: Are curly braces around the member variable correct syntax?

Comment: @Walkerneo [they are](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). (link is to "Variable variables" which doesn't apply, but it demonstrates how the braces are used to encapsulate the variable name.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you don't have a member variable initialized which matches YOUR_CLASS::$lib_SOMELIB, so PHP is throwing a notice.

I would try something like:

```
if ((!isset($this->lib_{$lib})) || 
    (!($this->lib_{$lib} instanceof $lib))) {
```

Also, you may want to look into using magic methods; [__set and __get](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) to dynamically set member variables of YOUR_CLASS, so you don't need to maintain a laundry list.

-- Edit #2 --

Not sure why you are getting the stdObject error, might be that already tried initializing the value earlier. Take a look at this snippet, and see if it helps. I tested it and works.

```
class strings
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        return __CLASS__;
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    private $dynamicMembers = array();

    public function loadLibs()
    {
        $libraries = array('strings');

        foreach ($libraries as $lib) {

            // Had to do it this way, b/c it was resulting in lib_ and not lib_strings
            $memberName = 'lib_' . $lib;

            if ((!isset($this->$memberName)) ||
                (!($this->$memberName instanceof $lib))) {
                var_dump(sprintf('I would have required: (%s)', 'lib/'.$lib.'.lib.php'));
                $this->$memberName = new $lib();
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->dynamicMembers[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->dynamicMembers)) {
            return $this->dynamicMembers[$name];
        }
    }
}

$myClass = new MyClass();

$myClass->loadLibs();

var_dump((string) $myClass->lib_strings);
var_dump($myClass->lib_strings);

exit;
```

-- Edit #1 --

After closer inspection of your code, it appears you are trying to create an autoloader coupled with a [lazy-load pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading). Lazy-loading works well in some situations, but keep in mind that it will be difficult for calling code to set specific member attributes of the objects being instantiated, if this is a non-issue, then disregard.

Also, I would recommend reading up on PHP's built-in [spl_autoload](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php) capabilities.

Comment: I'm still getting the 500 error, but now nothing is coming up in my error log, so now I'm even more confused D:

Comment: Hmmm not sure about that, chances are the conditional now passes and you are deeper in your code. Trying doing a `php -l` (lint check) against the file in question and make sure it compiles.

Comment: So the 500 errors were being caused by me having the require INSIDE the if statement (it couldn't see if `$this->lib{$lib}` was an `instanceof $lib` because the class is defined in the required file which hasn't been included yet). I feel stupid.

Anyway, now i get: `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home/clickash/public_html/system/core.lib.php on line 50` (line 50 being the if statement)

Answer (score 0):

Would the following work better for you?

```
class Library_Loader {
    protected $_loadedLibraries = array();

    public function load($library) {
        if (!array_key_exists($library, $this->_loadedLibraries)) {
            $path = realpath('lib/' . $library . '.lib.php');

            if (false === $path) {
                throw new Exception("Invalid library $library");
            }

            require_once $path;
            $this->_loadedLibraries[$library] = new $library();
        }

        return $this->_loadedLibraries[$library];
    }
}

$libraries = array('strings');
$loader = new Library_Loader;

foreach ($libraries as $library) {
    $loader->load($library);
}
```

You could also look at [wrapping this up into an autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) so that you could simply call `new strings();` in your code and have the class automatically loaded for you.